# What is the limit of redirects for Apache Tomcat 2.4?

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

We are replatforming to a new ecommerce system on a new server and due to SEO concerns, marketing is requesting we put a bit over 1000 product redirects into a rewrites.conf file. I have never seen this many redirects added. Is this possible without effecting the server response time significantly?

Answer (score 0):

We tested without redirects, added 1200 - 301 redirects and tested page load speed again. There was no measurable difference in page load speed. Just posting this in case somebody is looking for info on this topic.